# Example AWS4 S3 POST signature calculation fails

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, digital-signature, sha256, hmac

```
var crypto = require('crypto')
var secret = 'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY'
var date = '20151229'
var region = 'us-east-1'
var service = 's3'
var terminator = 'aws4_request'

var policyEncoded = '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'

console.log('Calculated answer:', crypto
    .createHmac('sha256', 'AWS4' + secret)
    .update(date)
    .update(region)
    .update(service)
    .update(terminator)
    .update(policyEncoded)
    .digest('hex'))

console.log('Correct answer   :', '8afdbf4008c03f22c2cd3cdb72e4afbb1f6a588f3255ac628749a66d7f09699e')
```

I wrote the code to calculate the signature for AWS4 S3 upload from the browser.
The example `StringToSign` comes from here:

[Signature v4 calculation example for POST](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html)

The expected output is also present on the same page.

The algorithm to sign is presented here:

[Calculating a signature v4 for POST](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-authentication-HTTPPOST.html)

But the result I am getting does not match the correct answer. Please help to locate the error.

I've googled and searched dozens of answers here on SO already, spend 10+ hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version of exebook answer:

```
var hmac = require('crypto').createHmac
var secret = 'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY'
var req = {
  date: '20151229',
  region: 'us-east-1',
  service: 's3',
  terminator: 'aws4_request',
  policyEncoded: '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'
}
var signature = Object.keys(req).
  reduce((h, k) => hmac('sha256', h).update(req[k]).digest(), 'AWS4' + secret).
  toString('hex')
console.log(signature)
//8afdbf4008c03f22c2cd3cdb72e4afbb1f6a588f3255ac628749a66d7f09699e
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because `.update()` merely writes new data into a hash stream. AWS requires you to hash the result of previous steps with a new key like this:

```
var x
x = crypto.createHmac('sha256', 'AWS4' + secret).update(date).digest()
x = crypto.createHmac('sha256', x).update(region).digest()
x = crypto.createHmac('sha256', x).update(service).digest()
x = crypto.createHmac('sha256', x).update(terminator).digest()
x = crypto.createHmac('sha256', x).update(policyEncoded).digest()
console.log('Calculated answer:', x.toString('hex'))
console.log('Correct answer   :', '8afdbf4008c03f22c2cd3cdb72e4afbb1f6a588f3255ac628749a66d7f09699e')
```

Output:

```
Calculated answer: 8afdbf4008c03f22c2cd3cdb72e4afbb1f6a588f3255ac628749a66d7f09699e
Correct answer   : 8afdbf4008c03f22c2cd3cdb72e4afbb1f6a588f3255ac628749a66d7f09699e
```